# IdentityServer4 .net core 3.1 No DbContext named 'ConfigurationDbContext' was found

Tags: c#, identityserver4, entity-framework-migrations, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to implement an identity provider using **IdentityServer4 (3.1.0)** and **.net core 3.1**
When I try to add a migration for the `ConfigurationDbContext`, it gives me the following error:

```
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.IntrospectionEndpoint Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.IntrospectionEndpoint': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Services.ITokenService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenService': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Services.IClaimsService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Validation.IEndSessionRequestValidator Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Validation.EndSessionRequestValidator': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Validation.ITokenRequestValidator Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Validation.ITokenValidator Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Validation.IIntrospectionRequestValidator Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Validation.IntrospectionRequestValidator': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Validation.IUserInfoRequestValidator Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Validation.UserInfoRequestValidator': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Validation.IDeviceCodeValidator Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.Validation.DeviceCodeValidator': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.ITokenResponseGenerator Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.IUserInfoResponseGenerator Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.IAuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.IAuthorizeResponseGenerator Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Guayaba.IDP2.Services.GuayabaUserRepository': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.) 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IdentityServer4.Services.IProfileService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Guayaba.IDP2.Services.GuayabaUserProfileService': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.)
No DbContext named 'ConfigurationDbContext' was found.
```

In my Startup.cs the `ConfigureServices` and the `Configure` methods are as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connectionString = Configuration["connectionStrings:UserDBConnectionString"];
            services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            services.AddScoped<IGuayabaUserRepository, GuayabaUserRepository>();

            var identityServerDataDBConnectionString =
               Configuration["connectionStrings:identityServerDataDBConnectionString"];

            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup)
                .GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddSigningCredential(LoadCertificateFromStore())
                .AddGuayabaUserStore()
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(identityServerDataDBConnectionString, sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(identityServerDataDBConnectionString, sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ConfigurationDbContext configurationDbContext,
            PersistedGrantDbContext persistedGrantDbContext)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            configurationDbContext.Database.Migrate();
            configurationDbContext.EnsureSeedDataForContext();

            persistedGrantDbContext.Database.Migrate();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

I have the following nuget packages installed:
IdentityServer4 (3.1.0)
IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation (3.0.1)
IdentityServer4.EntityFrameworkCore (3.1.0)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (3.1.0)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (3.1.0)

The error described happens after I try to perform this command in the package manager console:

`Add-migration IdentityServerInit -context ConfigurationDbContext`

I've been scouring the web since yesterday and still no answer. I've read many questions with the same issue here in stackoverflow and in github, but so far no luck. I've even created the whole project from scratch, just to see if I went wrong somewhere and nothing (yet). The error message doesn't make sense to me because I'm not registering anything as a singleton, least of all my repository.

However it is worth noting, that I cannot do an add-migration for my own context if I don't comment the services.AddIdentityServer portion on ConfigureServices.

Would you guys have any ideas on how to go about this?
Thanks!

Comment: does the error just occur when adding the migration or does the error happen when running the api as well?

Comment: does `UserContext` depend on IGuayabaUserRepository ?

Comment: Hi Bill, since I couldn't add the migration I hadn't try to run it until you asked. But yes, it happens also when running the api specifically in Program.Main CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint': Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'Guayaba.IDP2.Entities.UserContext' from singleton 'Guayaba.IDP2.Services.IGuayabaUserRepository'.```

Comment: And to answer your other question, UserContext is used by GuayabaUserRepository, the implementation of IGuayabaUserRepository

Comment: does the `.AddGuayabaUserStore()` extension method register the IGuayabaUserRepository as a singleton in some way? The error  you're seeing seems like somehow `IGuayabaUserRepository` is being registered as a singleton. Because it's a singleton, it can't take in the UserContext because EF contexts will always be registered as scoped

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks so much. It was indeed registered in the AddGuayabaUserStore as singleton. I totally spaced that I did that and was wrecking my brain trying to understand because I was just looking at the startup and of course addcontext will register it as scoped. So I didn't get it, but I changed it now as scoped and it works. Would you mind answering that so I can mark you as correct?